# Put images in the slider after image upload

Tags: jquery, image-uploading

I want to make, put images in to the slider after images uploading. But only reading first working code. It has two li elements and show this.  li elements increasing after uploading
This code  easysliders code. I am giving manuel s variable value, for example 100. Not have a problem  after this. How set automatic value for s variable after uploading?.

**CSS**

```
<div id="container">
   <div id="content">
    <div id="slider">
     <ul>    
      <li><a href="http://templatica.com/preview/30"><img src="./img/01.jpg" alt="Css Template Preview" /></a></li>
      <li><a href="http://templatica.com/preview/30"><img src="./img/01.jpg" alt="Css Template Preview" /></a></li>
     </ul>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

**Image Upload**

```
var uploader = $('#flashUploader').pluploadQueue();     
  uploader.bind('FileUploaded', function(up, file, response) {
   var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(response.response); 
    $('#slider ul').append("<li id="+obj.ramdom+"><img src='http://www.smyrnart.com/upl/" + obj.file + "'></li>")
   $("#slider").easySlider({
   a  : $("#slider ul li").length 
 });

 });
```

**Easy Slider**

```
this.each(function() {  
   var obj = $(this);  
   var s = options.a;
   alert(s);
   var w = $("li", obj).width(); 
   var h = $("li", obj).height(); 
   obj.width(w); 
   obj.height(h); 
   obj.css("overflow","hidden");
   var ts = s-1;
   var t = 0;
   $("ul", obj).css('width',s*w);   
   if(!options.vertical) $("li", obj).css('float','left');

   if(options.controlsShow){
    var html = options.controlsBefore;
    if(options.firstShow) html += '<span id="'+ options.firstId +'"><a href=\"javascript:void(0);\">'+ options.firstText +'</a></span>';
    html += ' <span id="'+ options.prevId +'"><a href=\"javascript:void(0);\">'+ options.prevText +'</a></span>';
    html += ' <span id="'+ options.nextId +'"><a href=\"javascript:void(0);\">'+ options.nextText +'</a></span>';
    if(options.lastShow) html += ' <span id="'+ options.lastId +'"><a href=\"javascript:void(0);\">'+ options.lastText +'</a></span>';
    html += options.controlsAfter;      
    $(obj).after(html);          
   };

   $("a","#"+options.nextId).click(function(){  
    animate("next",true);
   });
   $("a","#"+options.prevId).click(function(){  
    animate("prev",true);    
   }); 
   $("a","#"+options.firstId).click(function(){  
    animate("first",true);
   });    
   $("a","#"+options.lastId).click(function(){  
    animate("last",true);    
   });  

   function animate(dir,clicked){
    var ot = t;    
    switch(dir){
     case "next":
      t = (ot>=ts) ? (options.continuous ? 0 : ts) : t+1;      
      break; 
     case "prev":
      t = (t<=0) ? (options.continuous ? ts : 0) : t-1;
      break; 
     case "first":
      t = 0;
      break; 
     case "last":
      t = ts;
      break; 
     default:
      break; 
    };
```

Thanks for answers.

Comment: PLEASE DON'T SHOUT (*edit*: emboss fixed the worst of it for you)

Comment: Please don't use all-caps in your title. People will read your question more likely if you don't.

Comment: ok I am sorry. Have an idea that question